# How to capitalize the first character of each word in a string using Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a columns named 'ENTIDAD_FEDEREATIVA' which contains the name of each state of Mexico in upper case and looks like this:

[image]

What I want to do is to pass from upper to lower each character of each string in that column except the first character, therefore, the column should look like this:

[image]

I've been trying to do something like this `UPPER(LEFT([ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA], 1)) + MID([ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA], 2)` but I got this error: *syntax error operand missing*. If anyone has a better idea I would really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `UPPER(LEFT([ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA], 1)) + MID([ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA], 2)` works for me. However, this function will only make the first letter to capital, since all of your words already are capital it won't be any visible change.

Comment: FYI, from v 2022, they have a function `PROPER` that converts text into Title Case. (https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_string.htm#PROPER)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no function for that in Tableau (similar to `=Proper()` in excel) however we can do a workaround.

Example data:

[image]

If we only have one word in each string (`One word only`), we can use:

```
UPPER(LEFT([ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA],1)) + LOWER(MID([ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA], 2, LEN([ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA]) -1))
```

But since we have more words we need the split the string and perform the above logic to each word.

We start with the strings that have most words.

`Third word` will have the formula (split string and take the third occurrence `SPLIT([ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA], " ",3)`:

```
UPPER(LEFT(SPLIT([ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA], " ",3),1)) + LOWER(MID(SPLIT([ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA], " ",3), 2, LEN(SPLIT([ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA], " ",3)) -1))
```

Everywhere when no third word is found it will return a "`Null`" value.
Therefore we wrap the formula in `IFNULL(<expr1>,<expr2>)`

Where `<expr1>` will be all the words (first word + second word + third word) since we want to return the full string. For the `<expr2>` aka "`Null`" values, we do the same, but now we go for `Second word`.

`Second word` formula (we change which word we should return in the split function, `SPLIT([ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA], " ",2)`:

```
UPPER(LEFT(SPLIT([ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA], " ",2),1)) + LOWER(MID(SPLIT([ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA], " ",2), 2, LEN(SPLIT([ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA], " ",2)) -1)),
```

With this logic we can extend this to 7 or 10 or how many words we might have in a "cell".

For three words the complete calculated field (`Calculation4`) will look like:

```
// Third word:
IFNULL(
UPPER(LEFT(SPLIT([ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA], " ",1),1)) + LOWER(MID(SPLIT([ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA], " ",1), 2, LEN(SPLIT([ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA], " ",1)) -1))
+ " " + 
UPPER(LEFT(SPLIT([ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA], " ",2),1)) + LOWER(MID(SPLIT([ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA], " ",2), 2, LEN(SPLIT([ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA], " ",2)) -1))
+ " " + 
UPPER(LEFT(SPLIT([ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA], " ",3),1)) + LOWER(MID(SPLIT([ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA], " ",3), 2, LEN(SPLIT([ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA], " ",3)) -1)),

// Second word:
IFNULL(
UPPER(LEFT(SPLIT([ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA], " ",1),1)) + LOWER(MID(SPLIT([ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA], " ",1), 2, LEN(SPLIT([ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA], " ",1)) -1))
+ " " + 
UPPER(LEFT(SPLIT([ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA], " ",2),1)) + LOWER(MID(SPLIT([ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA], " ",2), 2, LEN(SPLIT([ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA], " ",2)) -1)),

// First word:
UPPER(LEFT(SPLIT([ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA], " ",1),1)) + LOWER(MID(SPLIT([ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA], " ",1), 2, LEN(SPLIT([ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA], " ",1)) -1))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your string has up to 1 space in it, this will work.

The spaces around [column_name] make it easier to double click to replace with your column name.

```
IF  CONTAINS( [column_name] , " ")

THEN
    UPPER( LEFT( [column_name] , 1) ) 

    +   LOWER( LEFT(
                    RIGHT( [column_name] 
                          , LEN( [column_name] ) - 1
                          )
                    ,FIND( [column_name] ," ") - 2
                    )
              )
    + " " 
    + UPPER(
            LEFT(
                RIGHT( [column_name] 
                      , LEN( [column_name] )
                      - FIND( [column_name] ," ")
                      )
                , 1
                )
            )
    + LOWER(
            RIGHT( [column_name] 
                , LEN( [column_name] )
                  - FIND( [column_name] ," ") - 1
               )
            )
ELSE
    UPPER( LEFT( [column_name] , 1) ) 

    +   LOWER( RIGHT( [column_name] 
                     , LEN( [column_name] ) - 1
                     )
             )

END
```

Answer (score 0):

I spilt up my main field using the space delimiter and then combined all split field using the below formula.

```
upper(left([Comments - Split 1],1))+ lower(right([Comments - Split 1],len([Comments - Split 1])-1)) + ' ' +
upper(left([Comments - Split 2],1))+ lower(right([Comments - Split 2],len([Comments - Split 2])-1)) + ' ' +
upper(left([Comments - Split 3],1))+ lower(right([Comments - Split 3],len([Comments - Split 3])-1)) + ' ' +
upper(left([Comments - Split 4],1))+ lower(right([Comments - Split 4],len([Comments - Split 4])-1)) + ' ' +
upper(left([Comments - Split 5],1))+ lower(right([Comments - Split 5],len([Comments - Split 5])-1))
```

However, this solution is not scalable, as we do not know how many words may occur in a sentence.